# Detecting non english characters in a string?

Tags: php, ascii

I'm trying to remove cached profiles which have non English letters in their description. I'm fine with dashes, symbols, special characters, underscores all that I just don't want foreign characters in my string.

The issue is, my code below detects strings with `á` as ASCII even though it isn't an English character, is matching against ASCII the right way?

```
if (!mb_detect_encoding($this->removeEmojis(str_replace(" ", "", $cacheItem->description), 'ASCII', true)))
{
    $cacheItem->delete(); // laravel
}
```

Value of `$cacheItem->description`

```
Welcome to my profile<br> Londrina-Paraná
```

The letter `á` is a non English character.

The description can also contain dots, symbols, special characters, but I want to detect foreign characters like Latin.

Descriptions can also contain emojis so I try to remove them with this function

```
private function removeEmojis($text){
    // theres lots more inside the preg_replace I truncated it for readability
    return preg_replace('/[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{E0067}\x{E0062}\x{E0077}\x{E006C}\x{E0073}\x{E007F})|[\x{1F3F4}]/u', ' ', $text);
}
```

Comment: Create a rule that whitelists what you WANT, everything else is what you don't want right?

Comment: `á` IS part of ASCII extended and has a decimal code of `160`

Answer (score 1):

You can detect any character that is not printable ASCII , by using this regexp

> [^\x20-\x7E]]*

[See ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Replace the matches with empty string then you get a purified one and then you can apply your emoji replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check if all the characters in the string are in the range `<space>` to `~` which is the ASCII character range:

```
$description = 'Welcome to my profile<br> Londrina-Paraná';
var_dump(preg_match('/^[ -~]*$/', $description));
$description = 'Welcome to my profile<br> Londriná-Parana';
var_dump(preg_match('/^[ -~]*$/', $description));
$description = 'Welcome to my profile<br> Londrina-Parana';
var_dump(preg_match('/^[ -~]*$/', $description));
```

Output:

```
int(0)
int(0)
int(1)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vQHeL)